# Does the Spring SqsListener wait until the last message is processed (or completed) from the current poll before the next poll of messages happens?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I have a SQS Listener with a max message count of 10. When my consumer receives a batch of 10 message they all get processed but sometimes (depending on the message) the process will take 5-6 hours and some with take as little as 5 minutes. I have 3 consumers (3 different JVM's) polling from the queue with a maxMessageCount of 10. Here is my issue:

If one of those 10 messages takes 5 hours to process it seems as though the listener is waiting to do the next poll of 10 messages until all of the previous messages are 100% complete. Is there a way to allow it to poll a new batch of messages even though another is still being processed?

I'm guessing that I am missing something little here. How I am using Spring Cloud library and the SqsListener annotation. Has anybody ran across this before?

Also I dont think this should matter but the queue is AWS SQS and there JVM's are running on an ECS cluster.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the task on the poller thread, the next poll won't happen until the current one completes.

You can use an `ExecutorChannel` or `QueueChannel` to hand the work off to another thread (or threads) but you risk message loss if you do that.

Your situation is rather unusual; 5 hours is a long time to process a message.

You should perhaps consider redesigning your application to persist these "long running" requests to a database or similar, instead of processing them directly from the message. Or, perhaps put them in a different queue so that they don't impact the shorter tasks.

Comment: I would recommend making a "bulk or long" process queue and a "regular" process queue so your regular processes don't get blocked by your long processes.